# How to make the hide and show animation of custom view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-animation

### Task:

I wanna hide and show my view with animation.

---

### Troubles:

First of all I tried to make it with changing view's visible (GONE, VISIBLE) (I use Transition API) but there were bugs with animation.

Then I tried to do it with scale animation but there was a bug with a hint in editText (child view).

---

### My custom view which I wanna animate:

```
class SearchAdditionalView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    private val transitionSet: TransitionSet by lazy {
        val transitionSet = TransitionSet()

        with(transitionSet) {
            addTransition(ChangeBounds())
            interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
            duration = 200
        }

        transitionSet
    }

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.include_search_navbar_addition, this)

    }

    fun toggle() {
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent as ViewGroup, transitionSet)
    }
}
```

---

### Question:

Are there good practices for this animation and how can I integrate it?

Comment: Are you starting off with View.GONE? If so, try starting with View.INVISIBLE. The system cannot measure a view with View.GONE set

Comment: @Redwine If I do this my view (without content) take a lot of important space

Answer (score 0):

`TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()` should be called first before making any changes to the `ViewGroup`. Check out the [training docs](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/) which should give you an idea.